# NSDateFormatter not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I dont know where I am lacking but I dont know why my NSDateformatter is not working.

My code is as follows:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatterObj = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[formatterObj setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
NSDate *newDate = [formatterObj dateFromString:@"2013-03-04 19:12:55 +0000"];
NSString *stringDate = [formatterObj stringFromDate:newDate];

NSLog(@"%@",stringDate);
```

it is printing a null object but I dont know why. Any help would be really grateful.

My desired output is in format "January 11, 2013"

Comment: You should note that you’re not only using the formatter to format the date but also to parse your input string. Most likely, not only `stringDate` is `nil` but also `newDate`. Try creating the `NSDate` object directly instead of parsing a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two formats. One to parse the original string. The second to generate the desired output. You are trying to parse the string with the output format. That won't work.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatterObj = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[formatterObj setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
NSDate *newDate = [formatterObj dateFromString:@"2013-03-04 19:12:55 +0000"];
[formatterObj setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
NSString *stringDate = [formatterObj stringFromDate:newDate];

NSLog(@"%@",stringDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your formatter should be:

```
[formatterObj setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
```

Comment: but i want date to be returned as "January 11, 2013"